# Metricsgraphics Date access - Line graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, metricsgraphicsjs

I am using the MetricsGraphic library for D3 visualization. For some reason, I can't figure out why my date parsing is not working.

```
d3.json('/api/data', function (data){
    data = MG.convert.date(data, "Date"["%d/%m/%y"]);
    MG.data_graphic({
        title: "Points per Matchday",
        description: "Points earned each matchday of 2014/2015 season",
        data: dataSet,
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        right: 40,
        target: document.getElementById('arsenalPoints'),
        x_accessor: 'Date',
        y_accessor: 'Points'
    });
});
```

I keep getting a type error saying that it `can't read property of 'time' undefined` with my `MG.convert.date` function. I also don't know if I'm formatting my date correctly.

Here is an example of my JSON:

```
{
    "Date" : "26/04/15",
    "HomeTeam" : "Arsenal",
    "AwayTeam" : "Chelsea",
    "FTR" : "D",
    "Points": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using MG:

This is wrong:

```
data = MG.convert.date(data, "Date"["%d/%m/%y"]);
```

This is right:

```
data = MG.convert.date(data, "Date", "%d/%m/%y");//its not an array
```

Full code below

```
d3.json('/api/data', function (data){
    data = MG.convert.date(data, "Date", "%d/%m/%y");//its not an array
    MG.data_graphic({
        title: "Points per Matchday",
        description: "Points earned each matchday of 2014/2015 season",
        data: data, // Send in our data
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        right: 40,
        target: document.getElementById('arsenalPoints'),
        x_accessor: 'Date',
        y_accessor: 'Points'
    });
});
```

Another way to do is this convert date using d3:

```
d3.json('/api/data', function (data){
  data.forEach(function(j){
    j.Date = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%y").parse(j.Date);//convert it into date
  });
  MG.data_graphic({
        title: "Points per Matchday",
        description: "Points earned each matchday of 2014/2015 season",
        data: data, // Send in our data
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        right: 40,
        target: document.getElementById('arsenalPoints'),
        x_accessor: 'Date',
        y_accessor: 'Points'
    });
});
```

Comment: works perfectly! But then I get another `Uncaught typeerror` at `MG.data_graphic` suspecting `sum is undefined.` I know I am sending in an array of objects (which I suspect is what you're supposed to do) since `api/data` is holding an array of the json I showed above.

Comment: sry i dont get any errors see my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/b2gxejgt/ may be this can help you fix your bug